# OpenCV - char vs. int

Tags: c++, opencv, char, int

In an from the `Learning OpenCV` book about reading an AVI video.

The program I typed is as follows:

```
char c = cvWaitKey(33);
if (c == 27) break;
```

As you can see, `c` was defined as `char`. How come the `if-statement` is comparing `c` with an `int`?

And, when we have this statement: `char c = cvWaitKey(33);`, what could the `char` value returned by `cvWaitKey(33);`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A `char` is just a number between -128 and 127 (or 0 and 255 if it is unsigned), usually, but not always, representing an ASCII character code.

The compiler has no problems implicitly converting an integer literal to a `char` if it falls within the valid range of values, which is what happens in the `if` statement.

The `cvWaitKey` function returns the character code of the key that was pressed. ASCII character code 27 happens to correspond to the ESC key.

The parameter to `cvWaitKey` (the 33) is the number of milliseconds to wait. Waiting 33ms on each frame (which is what I expect is happening) means the application is running at 30fps.